Can't restart mobile application in react native
Here is the code which should restart my application :
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

const VerificationCodeScreen = ({ navigation }: VerificationCodeScreenProps) => {

  const { updateAuth0Config } = useAuth0Config();
  
  const verifyCode = async () => {
    await updateAuth0Config('hey', 'yo');
    RNRestart.restart();
  }

I test my application with android device conected and this command :
react-native run-android
When I execute this function (which is on a button). I got the following error :
"Unable to determine default activity for com.testapp. Does an activity specify the DEFAULT category in its intent filter?"
I tried many things but I think my manifest should be ok :
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data
                    android:scheme="scheme"
                    android:host="host"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/com.testapp/callback"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`

I tried :
./gradlew clean
./gradlew clean build
./gradlew assembleDebug
I deleted node_modules and did :
npm install
